# deleting a point from array in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I just have to delete an element at position i .How can I directly delete the element.is there any direct function.I just want to delete arr[i] from the array. How can I do it i flex 3.0.

```
indexpoly = 3;

for(indexpoint = 0; indexpoint < indexpoly; indexpoint++)
{ 
    temp.points[indexpoint].x = intpoints[indexpoint].x+this.x;
    temp.points[indexpoint].y = intpoints[indexpoint].y+this.y;
}

for(indexpoint = indexpoint + 1; indexpoint <= intpoints.length; indexpoint++)
{
    temp.points[indexpoint-1].x = intpoints[indexpoint].x + this.x;
    temp.points[indexpoint-1].y = intpoints[indexpoint].y + this.y;
}
```

It doesnt work when I do this.

Comment: Your last three questions on SO are almost the same... are you sure that your `temp.points` array is not the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.splice()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29).

```
var index:int = 3;
temp.points.splice(index, 1);
```